# VBA Split on column - multiple variables

Tags: excel, vba, split

I have a VBA code that splits my data into seperate worksheets, based on the variables in a chosen column.
This works great, however I have a few variables that I want in the same sheet, dispite having a different name.

Example:

In column B I have company A, B, C, D & E. These companies gets split into different worksheets.
However, company A & C has the same parent company, and therefore should be in the same worksheet.

How can i add this to my code, if I include a table like below in my file?

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Company A | Group 'World' |
| Company B | Group 'Other' |
| Company C | Group 'World' |
| Company D | Group 'Other' |
| Company E | Group 'Other' |

```
Sub Step1_split()
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim vcol, i As Integer
    Dim icol As Long
    Dim myarr As Variant
    Dim title As String
    Dim titlerow As Integer

    'This macro splits data into multiple worksheets based on the variables on a column found in Excel.
    'An InputBox asks you which columns you'd like to filter by, and it just creates these worksheets.

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    vcol = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Which column would you like to filter by?", title:="Filter column", Default:="2", Type:=1)
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, vcol).End(xlUp).Row
    title = "A1"
    titlerow = ws.Range(title).Cells(1).Row
    icol = ws.Columns.Count
    ws.Cells(1, icol) = "Unique"
    For i = 2 To lr
        On Error Resume Next
        If ws.Cells(i, vcol) <> "" And Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ws.Cells(i, vcol), ws.Columns(icol), 0) = 0 Then
            ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, icol).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = ws.Cells(i, vcol)
        End If
    Next

    myarr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Columns(icol).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))
    ws.Columns(icol).Clear

    For i = 2 To UBound(myarr)
        ws.Range(title).AutoFilter field:=vcol, Criteria1:=myarr(i) & ""
        If Not Evaluate("=ISREF('" & myarr(i) & "'!A1)") Then
            Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = myarr(i) & ""
        Else
            Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Move after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
        End If
        ws.Range("A" & titlerow & ":A" & lr).EntireRow.Copy Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Range("A1")
        'Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Columns.AutoFit
    Next

    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    ws.Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I have tried adding an IF formula in the code, but have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a sheet named "Groups" for your table of relationships. Build an array of company names to use in the filter criteria.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Step1_split()

    Dim wb As Workbook, wsGroups As Worksheet
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsTarget As Worksheet
    
    Dim rngFilter As Range, rngCopy As Range
    Dim lastrow As Long, r As Long, grp As String
    Dim i As Long, n As Long, arCrit, vcol
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    With wb
         Set wsSrc = .Sheets(1) '.ActiveSheet
         Set wsGroups = .Sheets("Groups") ' as req
    End With
    
    vcol = Application.InputBox( _
        prompt:="Which column would you like to filter by ?", _
        title:="Filter column", Default:="2", Type:=1)
        
    If vcol = "False" Then Exit Sub ' cancel
    
    ' filter range
    With wsSrc
         lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, vcol).End(xlUp).Row
         Set rngFilter = .Cells(1, vcol).Resize(lastrow)
         Set rngCopy = .Cells(1, 1).Resize(lastrow)
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
    
    ' get parent-company details
    Dim dict As Object, k
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    With wsGroups
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For r = 2 To lastrow
            grp = Trim(.Cells(r, "B"))
            If Not dict.exists(grp) Then
               dict.Add grp, New Collection
            End If
            dict(grp).Add Trim(.Cells(r, "A"))
        Next
    End With
    
    ' create sheet for each group, clear existing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    i = wb.Sheets.Count
    For Each k In dict.keys
        grp = Replace(CStr(k), "'", "") ' take out single quotes
      
        On Error Resume Next
        Set wsTarget = wb.Sheets(grp)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If wsTarget Is Nothing Then
            wb.Sheets.Add(after:=wb.Sheets(i)).Name = grp
            i = i + 1
            Set wsTarget = wb.Sheets(i)
        Else
            wsTarget.Cells.Clear
        End If
        
        ' create aray
        ReDim arCrit(0 To dict(k).Count - 1)
        For n = 1 To dict(k).Count
            arCrit(n - 1) = dict(k)(n)
        Next
        'Debug.Print k, Join(arCrit, ";")
    
        ' filter with array as criteria and copy
        With rngFilter
             .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=arCrit, _
                         Operator:=xlFilterValues
             rngCopy.Copy wsTarget.Range("A1")
        End With
        Set wsTarget = Nothing
    
    Next
    wsSrc.AutoFilterMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Done"
   
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, for your reply.
When I try your code, it creates sheets bases on the groups in my table, but the sheets do not contain any data.

Comment: @andreas Uncomment the line `'Debug.Print k, Join(arCrit, ";")` and check immediate window, Comment out the last `wsSrc.AutoFilterMode = False` and check filter values for the last group. Single step the program and check what the filter criteria applied is.